# Compiler does not support #pragma once

Tags: thrust, pragma, include-guards, pgi

I have a compiler (PGI) that does not support

```
#pragma once
```

but the library (thrust) I would like to include uses them.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I don't know how much good or bad my answer is considered here in SO, so I put it just as a comment: I would write a program or script which would scan the library's directory and generate the standard guard. On Linux-like systems you usually do not have right to change installed files (and I even wouldn not recommend to), so I would create a copy, just for the project.

Comment: Yet another reason to use `#ifndef` header guards.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [guardonce](https://github.com/cgmb/guardonce) to convert the `#pragma once` statements to standard `#ifndef ...` include guards.

The following worked for me:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/thrust/thrust.git
git clone https://github.com/cgmb/guardonce.git
cd guardonce
git checkout v2.0.0
python -m guardonce.once2guard -r "/tmp/thrust/thrust/"
```

This creates the include guards in every thrust header file:

```
 git diff /tmp/thrust


--- a/thrust/adjacent_difference.h
+++ b/thrust/adjacent_difference.h
@@ -19,7 +19,8 @@
  *  \brief Compute difference between consecutive elements of a range
  */

-#pragma once
+#ifndef ADJACENT_DIFFERENCE_H
+#define ADJACENT_DIFFERENCE_H

. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, macros (and therefore #pragma) are handled by the preprocessor (cpp, not to be mistaken with c++ extension), so theoretically you could try using a preprocessor that supports #pragma, and then build the resulting code with your compiler.